# Como obter registros de uma tabela quando não há relacionamento com outra tabela em Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

No Laravel, quando quero obter dados de  uma tabela que contenha algum relacionamento, ou quando quero obter os dados a partir de uma condição de uma tabela relacionada, por exemplo, `usuarios` que contenha `livros`, eu utilizo os método `has` ou `whereHas`.

Assim:

```
 Usuario::has('livros')->get();
```

Ou assim:

```
 Usuario::whereHas('livros', function ($query)
 {
      $query->where('titulo', '=', 'Harry Potter');
 })->get();
```

Porém agora eu preciso da situação inversa.

Quero capturar apenas usuários que não contenham relacionamentos com `Livros`.

Quero capturar apenas usuários que não cotenha relacionamentos com livros do `Harry Potter`.

Como posso fazer isso no Laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já que ninguém respondeu, eu respondo.

Basta utilizar os métodos `doesntHave` e `whereDoesntHave`.

Por exemplo, quero todos os `usuários` que não possuam o `nível` 'admin', sendo que ambos tem um relacionamento `N:N`.

```
$usuarios = Usuario::whereDoesntHave('niveis', function ($query)
{
     $query->where('nome', '=', 'admin');

})->get();
```

Se eu quiser agora apenas os usuários que não possuam nenhum relacionamento com `niveis`, então podemos usar simplesmente `doesnHave`

```
  Usuario::doesntHave('niveis')->get();
```

Nessa [resposta em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089820/where-not-in-pivot-table/27742997#27742997), também há alguns exemplos que eu coloquei lá.

Comment: Essa eu sabia rs