# Laravel - Busca se existir relação na tabela muitos-pra-muitos

Tags: mysql, laravel, modelo-relacional

Preciso pesquisar os usuários de acordo com alguns atributos do filtro.

Tenho a tabela **contatos**:

```
id | nome | email
 1 | asd  | asd@gmail.com
 2 |teste | teste@gmail.com
```

A tabela **grupos**:

```
id | grupo
 1 | grupo1
 2 | grupo2
```

E a tabela **grupo_contato**:

```
id | id_grupo | id_contato
 1 |    1     |     1
 2 |    1     |     2
 3 |    2     |     1
```

No formulário do sistema de pesquisa eu listo em checkbox(para escolher quantos quiser) todos grupos da tabela. E preciso utilizar esse filtro de grupos.

Por enquanto meu código está assim:

```
public function search(Request $request){
        $grupo = $request->grupo;

        $callbackSearch = function ($query) use($request){
            $campos = ['nome', 'sexo', 'email'];
            foreach ($request->only($campos) as $campo => $valor){
                $valor && $query->where($campo, 'like', $valor);
            }

        };

        $request = Contato::where($callbackSearch)->paginate(15);

        return view('people.list')
            ->with('r', $request)                
    }
```

Tava tentando usar **Join** e **SELECT** dentro de **WHERE** mas não funfou.

**Terá diversos grupos.**

Comment: A pergunta que respondi  hoje resolve seu problema

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127252/como-obter-registros-de-uma-tabela-quando-n%C3%A3o-h%C3%A1-relacionamento-com-outra-tabela

Comment: Olá, gostaria que desse o retorno se isso resolveu o problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondi uma pergunta parecida com isso aqui hoje. Você deverá usar o método `whereHas`, para pesquisar os grupos relacionados com esse usuário.

Veja:

```
public function search(Request $request)

{

    $callbackSearch = function ($query) use($request) {

        $campos = ['nome', 'sexo', 'email'];

        foreach ($request->only($campos) as $campo => $valor){
            $valor && $query->where($campo, 'like', $valor);
        }

        $grupos = $request->get('grupos');

        // Só executa a query se grupos tiver algo

        $grupos && $query->whereHas('grupos', function ($query) use($grupos)
        {
            // Creio que o grupo seja um array, já que é N para N

            $query->whereIn('id', $grupos);
        });

    };

    $request = Contato::where($callbackSearch)->paginate(15);

    return view('people.list')
        ->with('r', $request)                
}
```

Relacionado:

- [Como obter registros de uma tabela quando não há relacionamento com outra tabela em Laravel?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127252/como-obter-registros-de-uma-tabela-quando-n%C3%A3o-h%C3%A1-relacionamento-com-outra-tabela)

Comment: Vlw, obrigado! Funcionou, mas não entendi muito bem a parte do: '$valor &&...'