# Trazer Registros Existentes e Não Existentes

Tags: mysql, laravel

Tenho a seguinte cena:

```
$consulta   = Dealer::find(1);
```

**No Model**

```
# Serviços
public function dealer_servicos(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\DealerService', 'id_concessionaria');
}
```

Daí se eu faço:

```
@foreach($consulta->dealer_servicos as $value => $res)
   {!! $res->servico !!}
@endforeach
```

Me traz todos os serviços que a concessionária **TEM**.

Tem como eu usar a mesma metodologia para trazer os serviços que a concessionária **NÃO TEM** ? Ou seja, simular o `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Preciso de todos os registros na mesma consulta.

Comment: Tem,  se você criar uma tabela com todos os serviços que a concessionaria deveria ter e depois selecionar todo esse itens e retirar os que a concessionária já tem.

Comment: Isso já existe, meu filho.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como obter registros de uma tabela quando não há relacionamento com outra tabela em Laravel?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127252/como-obter-registros-de-uma-tabela-quando-n%c3%a3o-h%c3%a1-relacionamento-com-outra-tabela)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estou percebendo que você está usando um `hasMany` de Dealer para DealerService. Creio que provavelmente você terá um relacionamento para `Dealer` dentro de `DealerService`.

Então, você pode usar o método `whereDoesntHave` para fazer isso.

```
$dealer = Dealer::find(1);

$dealerServices = DealerService::whereDoesntHave('dealers', function ($query) use($dealer)
{
        $query->where(['id' => $dealer->id]);

})->get();
```

Se notar, vai perceber que a pequena diferença é que essa consulta deve ser feita "fora do relacionamento".

Expressando em palavras, o método `whereDoesntHave` tem como finalidade fazer um "Quando DealerService não tiver relacionamento com Dealer de id 1".

Comment: Mas ele vai trazer todos na mesma consulta ?

Comment: Sim, mas se quiser usar o Paginate não tem problemas

Comment: Eu vou testar, se não trazer tudo vou até MG dá um murro no meio da sua boca.